# Android : Advance/Future purchase in google play Billing library

Tags: android, subscription, google-play-billing

I am using In-app purchase subscriptions in my app and using 5.0.0 Play billing library.
I need to make an advance payment ie: take payment 20days before the billing date. I can't find any such way to do the same in google play billing library. Help will be appreciated.

Thanks